# Pycharm Matplotlib backend doesn't change from Agg

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

Matplotlib resorts to Agg no matter what backend I give it.

Things I've tried:

1. Changing the backend using matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg') and matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg', force=True)

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg', force=True)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

2. Changing the backend in the matplotlibrc file

```
## ***************************************************************************
## * BACKENDS                                                                *
## ***************************************************************************
## The default backend.  If you omit this parameter, the first working
## backend from the following list is used:
##     MacOSX Qt5Agg Gtk3Agg TkAgg WxAgg Agg
## Other choices include:
##     Qt5Cairo GTK3Cairo TkCairo WxCairo Cairo
##     Qt4Agg Qt4Cairo Wx  # deprecated.
##     PS PDF SVG Template
## You can also deploy your own backend outside of matplotlib by referring to
## the module name (which must be in the PYTHONPATH) as 'module://my_backend'.
#backend: Qt5Agg
```

Printing the backend gives the following:

```
print(matplotlib.get_backend())
print(matplotlib.is_interactive())

Qt5Agg
False
```

Yet when I try to use `plt.show()` the following error occurs:

```
UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.
plt.show()
```

I don't know wether this is a Pycharm or Matplotlib error.
Hope you guys have any ideas

Shkar

Comment: For those running in to this problem aswell.
A very dirty fix is to add everytime `plt.switch_backend('Qt5Agg')` before showing the plot.

Answer (score 1):

In my case (Linux Mint 20.3) the issue came from installing PyCharm from the Software Manager. PyCharm then was installed with flatpak

```
flatpak list
```

should give show you an idea if it is so too.

There are issues with that version. Have a look at:
https://github.com/flathub/com.jetbrains.PyCharm-Community/issues/15

I could fix it by installing PyCharm with snapd.
https://thesecmaster.com/3-ways-to-install-pycharm-on-linux-mint-and-ubuntu/

then: `sudo apt-get install python3.8-tk`
and within PyCharm I had to add

"future" and "matplotlib"

More information about it:
When you run PyCharm the first time (installed from Software Manager) you receive:

> https://www.flathub.org

---

### | Warning: You are running an unofficial Flatpak version of PyCharm !!! |

Please open issues under: https://github.com/flathub/com.jetbrains.PyCharm-Community/issues

This version is running inside a container and is therefore not able
to access SDKs on your host system!